# Why am I getting an "unexpected T_STRING error"

Tags: php, zend-framework, .htaccess

I'm trying to get Zend Amf working on my hosting services (Lunarpages, if that matters).  I can get it working on my local machine, but after changing a few directories and posting the code, I keep getting this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting '{' in /home/user_name/public_html/library/Zend/Amf/Server.php on line 57
```

Normally this issue is a syntax error, and I am enough of a n00b that I can't discount that.  But I have cut down the code to just this:

```
<?php
$clientLibraryPath = '/home/user_name/public_html/library/';
$oldPath = set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $clientLibraryPath);

require_once('Zend/Amf/Server.php');

?>
Delicious turkey legs!
```

Here are lines 57/58 from the Zend_Amf_Server.php file (preceding lines are just more includes for Zend Amf):

```
class Zend_Amf_Server implements Zend_Server_Interface
{
```

and I am still getting the error.  Could this be something in my config?  I tried to set up my .htaccess the way Wade Arnold recommends [here](http://wadearnold.com/blog/flash/bootstrap-file-for-zend-amf), but I am getting errors unless I comment out the lines beginning with php_value and php_flag.  Could this be linked to my error?  Or am I barking up the wrong tree entirely?

Thanks.
- Dave

Comment: Which version of the Zend framework do you use? If it's some bleeding edge beta, there could really be an error in the Zend file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running PHP4 on the server then '`implements Zend_Server_Interface`' will be unexpected because interfaces were not supported then, and it will instead expect the opening brace.

Comment: I disabled and re-enabled PHP5 on Lunarpages and it started working, so I think it was related to this.

Answer (score 2):

The error is in Zend/Amf/Server.php
Please show the code around line 57 (if possible, 5 to 10 lines before and after).

Disabling error reporting will only hide errors, not prevent them.

Comment: Sorry, that line is trivial so I did not bother including it.  I've edited my question to show it.

Comment: That line is not trivial if it's the line the reporting is mentioning :)

Comment: what is the last line with code **before** line 57? If the unexpected T_STRING is the 'class', then the error lies in the line before.